# Deleting an element from redis list with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I was trying to  manage a list in redis with nodejs. I am able to store list with following code :

```
client.rpush(['room_'+room, data.customClient], function(err, reply) {

        client.lrange('room_'+room, 0, -1, function(err, reply) {
          console.log(reply);
      });
    });
```

The console output is

> [ 'POanqn9llyTcuIurUPAN', 'm9vd57wecp6JvtHOrRSJ' ]

Now I want to delete one key  **POanqn9llyTcuIurUPAN** from this list. How can I do this ?

Comment: Your Redis client should have an interface to the `LREM` command: http://redis.io/commands/lrem

Comment: Yes, But in Node.js library how can I call LREM ??

Comment: Perhaps call `client.lrem('room_'+room,reply,1);` where you log the reply from lrange

Comment: Note, however, that lpop is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @ItamarHaber can you please tell the syntax for lpop, I didn't find it in documentation.

Comment: Should be as simple as `client.lpop('room_'+room, function...);` - http://redis.io/commands/lpop

Answer (score 1):

It can be done through `lrem` command. The usage to delete all the entries with that value will be:

```
client.lrem('room_'+room, data.customClient, 0, 'POanqn9llyTcuIurUPAN', function(err, data){
    console.log(data); // Tells how many entries got deleted from the list
});
```

Here *0* is a count telling delete all the entries with the value *POanqn9llyTcuIurUPAN* in the given list. From https://redis.io/commands/lrem the possible values of the count could be:

- count > 0: Remove elements equal to value moving from head to tail.
- count < 0: Remove elements equal to value moving from tail to head.
- count = 0: Remove all elements equal to value.

Comment: Why is data.customClient, passed into the lrem?

Comment: so wierd, you can access by index but not remove by index. why. not o(1). requires search for value. further you can not say to a list to remove a value starting from a certain index. its either head or tail meaning you can not be sure to be removing the same index.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done easily like this:

```
client.lrem('room_'+room, 0, 'POanqn9llyTcuIurUPAN', function(err, data){
    console.log(data); // Tells how many entries got deleted from the list
});
```